# Why are core beliefs often phrased as opposites?

Tags: terminology, human-factors, happiness

I was reading about core beliefs ([here](https://www.therapistaid.com/worksheets/core-beliefs.pdf) and [here](https://betterrelationships.org.au/well-being/core-beliefs-self-acceptance/)). While I get the definition, the examples seem very simple to me. For example "I'm ugly" vs "I'm beautiful". Don't most people accept that things exist in a continuum or range? For example I might believe the world is **generally safe** but still lock my door at night. Why is there this false dichotomy when it comes to core beliefs, or am I mistaking?